# Spark writing to hive as ORC error: Path is not a file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark code which is trying to write to hive ORC table
**Spark Version: 2.2.0.2.6**

I created a dataframe and when I do `DF.show(10)` I am able to see the data and the column are also matching. But when I try to save it to the hive ORC table using below code.

`DF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("orc").saveAsTable(hive_stgtableName)`

or

`DF.repartition(5).write.mode("Append").insertInto(hive_stgtableName_PReq)`

The error which I am getting is below.

`Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Path is not a file: /apps/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mydb/hive_stgtableName`

This hive_stgtableName is pointed to

/apps/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mydb/hive_stgtableName.

Now everytime whenever I run this code after recreating the hive table, I am getting random dir's but same error.

`/apps/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mydb/xx_1`

`/apps/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mydb/xx_2`

`/apps/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mydb/xx_3`

I tried will all table recreation but the error is still coming out.
Basically its throwing error randomly for all the directories which are in the same level of `/apps/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mydb/hive_stgtableName`

MY hive Table statement is below

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.hive_stgtableName(
  headertimestamp string,
  recordtype string,
  messageid string,
  myattri_chn_updatesallowed string,
  myattri_chn_messageid string,
  myattri_chn_version string,
  myattri_chn_identity string,
  myattri_chn_system string,
  myattri_chn_xmlns_ns2 string,
  myattri_chn_xmlns_soap string,
  myattri_chn_xmlns_ns3 string,
  myattri_chn_xmlns_ns4 string,
  syscontext_servgrp string,
  syscontext_ntwk string,
  syscontext_ch string,
  syscontext_zone string,
  syscontext_session string,
  service_id string,
  myval_contmyval_id string,
  myval_contmyval_assetref_providerid string,
  myval_contmyval_assetref_assetid string,
  climyval_currentdatetime string,
  climyval_terminaladdr_type string,
  climyval_terminaladdr string,
  climyval_targetcode_key string,
  climyval_targetcode string,
  placemtopp_id string,
  placemtopp_serregref string,
  hashed_header_id string,
  input_file_name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/apps/dir1/dir1/dir1/dir1/mydb/hive_stgtableName'
TBLPROPERTIES ('orc.compress'='SNAPPY');`

Any idea what might be causing this error. I tried a lot googling but nowhere this error is pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
saveAsTable(mydb.hive_stgtableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was while reading the files(which contained more than 300+), there were directory also in the same location. Spark is weird in the sense that when I try to do DF.show(10) its still shows me the correct output but when I try to write the data to a table, that time it throws an error and everytime it shows random directory. Hence by making sure it reads only the files as input, this error was gone.